Is a painting "made by" a painter or just "by" a painter?
Unbelievably and infuriatingly, as a result of proofreading my paper, I managed to create and insert a typo while correcting other mistakes. It was actually correct before.
The first line is now:

Der Traum des Hirten is an oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918) in 1896."

Instead of writing:

Der Traum des Hirten is an oil painting made by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918) in 1896."

We have a example just like the above sentence in a writing guide for the class and I somehow managed to do it, as a result of editing while proofreading.
So, according to this writing guide by Marjorie Munsterbeg, I should have written "..a painting made by....in 1896" because to leave out the "made" makes the "in 1896" at the end of the sentence ambiguous as it's unclear to what the "in 1896" is in reference to.
But is the first line grammatically incorrect or just bad writing?
I feel like I should email my professor and just preemptively apologize and acknowledge the mistake.
UPDATE 7/1/24: got an A+ on the paper and this professor didn't even notice the poorly worded first line.....

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The word made does not collocate well with the noun painting. It is not at all idiomatic to say that a painter "made" a painting, as can be seen in this Google Ngrams chart comparing the frequency of the two alternatives:

View interactive chart on Google Ngrams site
You can see that "a painting by..." is a common phrase, while "a painting made by" barely shows up at all.

The most common and natural-sounding verb to describe the action of an artist producing a painted work is to paint. But, saying that the "painter painted a painting" does sound repetitious, so I see why you'd want to avoid that.
This means that the issue of the time adverbial in 1896 being stranded after the deletion of the verb "made" from your original sentence might be better addressed in a different manner. Maybe you could rephrase the sentence to something like the following:

"Der Traum des Hirten is an 1896 oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918)."

where the time expression "1896" modifies "oil painting" instead of the (now nonexistent) verb. This construction is analogous to (for the sake of example) describing a vehicle as "a 2008 Chevy."

You also say in your question that "I feel like I should email my professor and just preemptively apologize and acknowledge the mistake," but this isn't the kind of thing that can be answered on EL&U. Questions about email etiquette in an academic setting are better fit for the Academia.SE site. While I'm not really qualified to offer advice in this area, an apology email does seem like it might be overreacting to a relatively minor issue - even the best writers miss the occasional typo! If it is possible, it might be better to send a correction with a revised version of the sentence and an

acknowledgement of the issue you are correcting, but again, whether or not an email is warranted at all is a question for the Academia site. https://academia.stackexchange.com/

“… is a painting in 1896” ?
The sentence does need correction. As it is now, your sentence breaks down to:

[Subject] is [Subject Complement]

[Der Traum des Hirten] is [an oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918) in 1896.]


Looking at the subject complement noun-phrase in your sentence, the use of “in” might be grammatically correct, but “an oil painting in 1986” makes little sense: the painting does not exist only in 1896 - it still exists now.
Your original sentence, “made by... in 1896” resolved this oddness by attaching that date to the act of creating the painting, rather than to the painting itself. (As already pointed out, writers of English don’t consider paintings to be “made”; we prefer “produced” or “created”.)
Rewording: “…from 1826”
If you’re looking for a minimal correction that makes your sentence make sense again, I’d suggest forgetting the word “made”, and saying this instead:

Der Traum des Hirten is an oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853–1918) from 1896.

“from 1896” refers to origin of the painting in time. (I just checked the Wikipedia page for this work, and that’s how the author has described the picture in the first sentence…)
If you were writing the sentence again, though, I would say this (with thanks to @TimR for the comment):

Der Traum des Hirten is an 1896 oil painting by the Swiss realist and symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853–1918).

(Note “an” because “eighteen ninety-six” begins with the vowel /eɪ/; contrast with “he won with a 1896 majority”, because “one thousand eight hundred and ninety-six” begins with the non-vowel /w/)
Art movements are not capitalised
As an aside, in normal English writing, we do not capitalise the names of movements when using them as adjectives. For example:

“Leon Trotsky was a communist theorist…” (source)
“…Salvador Dalí was Spanish surrealist painter”(source)
“Unlike his previous, more realist works, Dream shows Hodler's interest in symbolism.” (source)

Note the last example does not capitalise “symbolism” even when it’s the name of the movement, and thus could be considered a proper noun. However, it could also be considered not as the name of a movement, but rather as a concept or an approach to painting; as such it wouldn’t get a capital letter.
However, if your organisation has a style-guide that says to capitalise the names of movements, then you should follow that guide, but be aware that it’s not normal in academic writing.

+1  How about: Der Traum des Hirten (1896)  is an oil painting by the Swiss realist and symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853–1918).

@TimR - yep, and that’s very close to the opening sentence of the Wikipedia article. I’d actually take the parentheses out and say “…is an 1896 oil painting by…”, but I was attempting to provide the OP with a minimal fix that they could pass off as a typo.   (although it their professor sees this, they can’t ;) )


The first line is now:
Der Traum des Hirten is an oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918) in 1896."

This is almost idiomatic, but should be
Der Traum des Hirten (1896) is an oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918)."

Instead of writing: "Der Traum des Hirten is an oil painting made by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918) in 1896."

This is quite poor and not idiomatic.
The verb "to make" is not normally used with paintings: the verb is usually "to do" (although there are more formal, less used, verbs)
Again, the painting's date should follow the title.


Der Traum des Hirten is an oil painting by the Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918) in 1896."

The revised sentence above is perfectly fine, the date of the painting could have been positioned closer to the object, but that is a question of style not grammar.
As many of the comments (which have now been migrated to chat) attested, the verb "made" is not usually collocated with painting, an alternative would be painted.
The OP's revised sentence can be recast:

Der Traum des Hirten, painted by Ferdinand Hodler in 1896, a Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist (1853-1918).

If the text is not accompanied by an image, or knowing which medium was used is central:

Der Traum des Hirten, painted/ executed in 1896, is an oil painting by Ferdinand Hodler (1853-1918), a Swiss Realist and Symbolist artist.

The MoMA (Metropolitan Museum of Art) website, lists works of arts in the following way:

   Pablo Picasso
   L'Age de soleil
  (Print executed 1944).

The British-founded Sotheby’s, lists works of art to be auctioned:

  Edward Hopper
  Oregon Coast
  signed Edward Hopper (lower right)
  watercolour on paper
  50.2 by 69.9cm.
  19 3/4 by 27 1/2 in.
  Executed in 1941.

Bravo @Kris W for spotting the OP's hypercorrect capitalisation of Realist and Symbolist artist. I think many of us missed that error, so I am in total agreement with the last paragraph in their answer. However, I disagree that "produced by" and "created by"– when referring to paintings–are preferred, and Google Ngram seems to confirm this.


One might criticise the recast 'sentence', for not being, by some standards, a sentence at all (no finite form of verb). And for the superfluity of the word artist.

@HighPerformanceMark Hmm… but it has the present form of he auxiliary "be" is. Is "He is tired" not a sentence?  If the original isn't a sentence by some, what would it be called?

@HighPerformanceMark I might criticise the criticism as being unnecessarily pedantic. What is wrong with calling someone who creates art using the  medium of oil paint an "artist"?

I don't see the word be (nor any variations of it) in the recast as first proposed. (Though I do see it in later suggestions.)  Further, isn't this whole site a temple for pedantry?

@Mari-LouA: It's definitely a sentence as far as I can see! As to the "artist" thing, there's nothing wrong with calling them that, but in the context it sounds slightly better to leave it out, because both "Realist" and "Symbolist" already imply "artist".

@HighPerformanceMark: Perhaps there's a confusion what you're referring to? I suspect you mean the one after "can be recast", but since you said "first" I (and I suspect Mari-Lou) initially assumed you meant the very first sentence in the post?

"is an oil painting ... by ... Hodler in 1896" isn't "perfectly fine" as it lacks a verb like "painted" or "executed" to support the use of in 1896. Without such a verbal adjective it should be "dating from 1896" or something like that.

@TimR  It's a semi-skeletal description, telegraphic, and to the point. And as we all know, ellipsis is very common in speech and in writing. it is hardly ambiguous or stilted. It sounds and reads fine to me.

@Mari-LouA Skeletal or not, it doesn't work with "in 1986" without something  that the prepositional phrase can pertain to.  KrisW in that answer makes much the same point.  "from 1896" sure, but not "in".
